# HttpURLConnection GET download file, doesn't return anything.

Tags: java, get, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection to download a xml file. I can see the file in my web browser, it takes over 10 seconds to load. But i can see the content eventually. But I am not able to download it through my java code. It seems like all my SetTimeOut() don't really work. Here is my code, please help:

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) laURL.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        con.setConnectTimeout(15*1000);
        con.setReadTimeout(15*1000);

        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

Comment: You don't need to set the `Content-Type` header in your **request**. This is telling the server that the content of the request body is of type `text/xml`. You don't have a request body. You might want `Accept` header.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...can you download it as a binary file?

Try this:

```
        con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "binary/data");

        try (InputStream in = con.getInputStream(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath))
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(b, 0, count);
            }
        }
```